# How can i toggle the value of an attribute like contenteditable in my angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

you see my directive to toggle (true/false) the state of a contenteditable element.
If i put the "editable" var into a ng-class, it changes correctly. but i'am not able to change the value of an attribute on click. How can i solve this problem, what i'am missing here?

```
app.directive('ContentEditable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      contenteditable: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div contenteditable="{editable}" ng-click="toggleEdit()" ng-transclude></div>',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,


    link: function($scope) {
      var state = $scope.editable;
      $scope.editable = state === undefined ? false : state;

      $scope.toggleEdit = function(){
        $scope.state = !$scope.state;
        $scope.editable = $scope.state;
      };
    }
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need double parens around the binded attribute value:

```
contenteditable="{{editable}}"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x918ewLo/

Comment: you changed the markup, right? because in my project setup i get this behavior http://jsfiddle.net/x918ewLo/

so can you explain me why it does not work with this(my) markup?

Comment: You did not share your markup with us. I basically improvised. I have no idea why it _still_ does not work for you because (1) that's another question and (2) you are not showing us the markup.

Comment: The changes in `template` are of no relevance. `contenteditable="{editable}" is wrong.

Comment: And here's a version that only changes what I wrote about in the _answer_: http://jsfiddle.net/qyc5vr9q/

Comment: my markup only consist of the template itself and this `<content-editable>some content here...</content-editable>`, your last link does not changes the value of contenteditable attribute

Comment: It does, it's not visible in Chrome Developer Tools. It does toggle the "editable" feature does it not?

Comment: i'am using FF, and sorry but unfortunately it does not change the attribute if you compare it to your first solution which works well but not with my usecase (click the element itself not on another link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format it worked for me

```
<div id="editableContent" ng-attr-contenteditable="{{editmode}}" ng-bind-html="Content"  ng-style="myStyle">
```